# How to paste in two columns without deleting the others

Tags: tabulator

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, two columns receive the data but the other columns are deleted and there is a new row

Tabulator 4.4 + Firefox 68

```
var mytable = new Tabulator("#Thetable", {
    layout:"fitColumns",
    clipboard:true,
    clipboardPasteAction:"replace",
```

All my screenshots : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nroy2.jpg

Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

I did it... Sorry for my post. I don't know if it's the good solution...
Here is my solution :

```
clipboard:true,
clipboardPasteAction:"replace",
clipboardPasteParser:function(clipboard){

pasterows=clipboard.split("\n");
clipboardArray=table.getData();
var numcol;

for (numcol = 0; numcol < pasterows.length-1; ++numcol) {
        twovalue=pasterows[numcol].split("\t");
        clipboardArray[numcol].identifiant=twovalue[0];
        clipboardArray[numcol].mdp=twovalue[1];
        }
   return clipboardArray;
},
```